# yii : how to display CJuiDialog when click button of cgridview?

Tags: php

Q : how to display CJuiDialog when click button of cgridview?

I would like to display the popup when user click the button of cgridview.

This is the button of cgridview

```
'buttons'=>array(
    'history'=>array(
        'visible'=>'Yii::app()->user->checkAccess("Reviewer") && $data->status == "Reviewing"',
        'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("/history/view", array("id"=>$data->id))',
        'imageUrl'=>Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/images/assets/history.png',   
                ),
```

But I'm really don't know how to do it. pls help me.

Answer (score 2):

First you setup the CJuiDialog:

```
$this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog', array(
    'id'=>'mydialog',
    // additional javascript options for the dialog plugin
    'options'=>array(
        'title'=>'Dialog box 1',
        'autoOpen'=>false,
    ),
));

echo 'dialog content here';

$this->endWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog');
```

Then you use the element 'click' of $buttons:

```
'click'=>'$("#mydialog").dialog("open"); return false;',
```

Comment: thx. I found it right now and testing on it. but what I found, I want to show the history of a user when admin click the user from grid view. According your, it is display the 100% data of history table. I don't know how to pass the user_id into dialogbox. 
I think, when the admin click the history button, it'll check and get the data from history by user_id. and render to list view.